# Why it becomes NoneType when I return an int?

Tags: python, class, integer, nonetype

Whenever I tried to run _classifier(), all the values in Labels were None. However, when I debugged it, I found that the value of Label in _classify() was 1 but it became NoneType object when it return to _classifier(). I have no idea why it is happening.

```
class DecisionTree:
def __init__(self, data,left=None,right=None,dtLeft=None,dtRight=None,split=None,sF=None,Label=None): 
    self.data=data
    self.left=left
    self.right=right
    self.dtLeft=dtLeft
    self.dtRight=dtRight
    self.split=split
    self.sF=sF
    self.Label=Label

def _classifier(self,data):
    Labels=[]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        Label=self._classify(data[i])
        Labels.append(Label)
    print(Labels)

def _classify(self,data):
    if self.Label is not None:
        Label=self.Label
        return Label
    else:
        if data[self.sF]<=self.split:
            self.dtLeft._classify(data)
        else:
            self.dtRight._classify(data)
```

Comment: Because `Label` is not the same as `self.Label`.  `Label` is a local variable that will go away when the function completes.  I think you have a confusion between `Label` and `Labels` in your code anyway.  What were you expecting to find in `self.Label`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually I tried to return self.Label in _classify() at the beginning but it return NonType to _classifier() even through the value in self.Label is 1.

Comment: You haven't provided an MRE, but `_classify` returns `None` any time it recurs, so I suspect that's the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @Samwise Oh yes! I know what's the problem now! Thanks!